# Very low power pulse generation switch-based circuit for MCU wake-up

Tags: analog

[image: analog circuit]

We have a circuit like the one I attached to this post.

The idea behind it is to generate a pulse every time the switch is closed.

We have two constraints for this circuit:

a. The pulse should be at least 50 micro-second

b. The max current of this circuit when the switch is on  should be less than 250 nA while the switch is closed (only the analog, without the MCU part)

However, This circuit suffers from unwanted pulses in the MCU IO pin because the pull-down resistor is too big.

How can we solve it?

Or design another circuit with these constraints (and also the pulses problem...)

Any ideas?

Comment: Why such a low ON current of 250 nA?

Comment: How often is the switch switched (ie, frequency)? What is the switch duty cycle? How long does it stay on/off?

Comment: What are the input characteristics of the GPIO pin? **Maximum** input leakage current and pin capacitance? What is the parasitic capacitance of the wiring?

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHP01L.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- the bounce time must be less than T, otherwise increase T

### Rev 1

- Added buffer hinted by Elliot.  (chose Schmitt Nand)
- corrected polarity for negative logic resets.
- added Power on Reset  (POR), low leakage Si diode.
- added Watch Dog Timer reset input (WDT) (useful)

For more wisdom, read what microchip say...

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/31003a.pdf

Comment: I don't think this will be reliable if it is connected to the input pin of a microcontroller, where the input capacitance may be 10pF and the input leakage current is up to +/- 1 microampere.

Comment: Yes then a Schmitt buffer is preferred. Leakage is worst at max temp.

Comment: I am concerned from the leakage current. Does not the Schmitt itself consume more than 1 uA?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 thanks. Still have some questions: I don't understand all the POR, WDT, diode and uC reset stuff. The pulse is not for reset is for counting. What about the schmitt? I understand it is good for leakage current - but the schmitt has its consumtion, is not it? In addition, the 33pF is enough for the unwanted pulses I get?

Comment: Define uC input used for wake up. I assumed it was  reset.. like Power on Reset POR.  My fault..